# Getting the error message: @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm getting the following error message from AS's Build Output:

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a
> @Composable function

It occurs when I try to call the IconButton compose function in of navigationIcon and actions parameters.

How could I fix that error in my code? I've been stuck in that one for few hours I don't know what to do anymore.

By the way I'm using Compose **version 1.0.3**.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowScope
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Menu
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Refresh
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent() {
            MainTheme()
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, name = "Text preview")
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MainTheme()
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}

@Composable
fun MainTheme() {
    TopAppBar(
        title = { "Coinwatcher" },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = null)
            }
        },
        actions = {
            IconButton(onClick = {/* doSomething() */}) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Refresh, contentDescription = null)
            }
        }
    )
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}

@Composable
fun TopAppBar(
    title: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigationIcon: () -> Unit,
    actions: RowScope.() -> Unit = {},
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    elevation: Dp = AppBarDefaults.TopAppBarElevation
): @Composable Unit { }


@Composable
fun IconButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource,
    content: () -> Unit
) { }

@Composable
fun Icon(
    painter: Painter,
    contentDescription: String?,
    modifier: Modifier,
    tint: Color
) { }
```

Comment: What is `doSomething()`?.Usually such a mistake is an attempt to call composable function in `onClick`

Comment: Just a comment "/* doSomething() */". Like decribed in this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#TopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)).

Comment: What is return type`: @Composable Unit { }`?

Comment: I fixed the post right now. Which one?

Comment: Just remove TopAppBar, IconButton, Icon from code file

Comment: Yeah, it's worked. Thanks.

Comment: Next Time, consider pressing F2 to go to the exact line of error, then try to debug. If  unable to debug still, then post only the required code block that you have isolated using the F2 key. You see it is hard to navigate through the entire code when half of it is not required to answer the question.